# Styling the traffic in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mapkit

Is there a way to change the style of the default traffic lines that appear when MKMapView.ShowsTraffic is set to true?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if Timo Salomäki's answer solved problem , remember to mark it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have probably already found out, the farthest you can go with traffic styling is exactly that one boolean variable [showsTraffic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452433-showstraffic) that either shows it or not. MapKit is not really customizable apart from annotations and that's what you have to live with if you're not willing to use a 3rd party map provider. In my mind you have two choises:

### Use a custom tile renderer with MKMapView

You can use the [MKTileOverlay](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlay) class coupled with the [MKTileOverlayRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mktileoverlayrenderer) to fetch map tiles from a 3rd party service that supports tile fetching and customization, and then show those tiles instead of the default Apple map. One such service is [Google Maps Tiles API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/#tile_requests) but you need to request access to it from Google (it's not part of the normal Google Maps API) and it's paid.

If you're still willing to go that route, you can follow the [Customize MapKit’s MKMapView with Google Maps styling wizard](https://medium.com/@ortizfernandomartin/customize-mapkits-mkmapview-with-google-maps-styling-wizard-a5dcc095e19f) article on how to create your custom style and use it to request tiles from the Google Server. **However, you should NOT use the Google Maps API address mentioned in the article, as circumventing the official Google API's and making requests straight to their servers is strictly not allowed and will get you banned and/or in trouble.** Instead, you should use the official API I linked to above.

### Use another map control altogether

I'm fully aware that the above is a lot work for just customizing the traffic lines, so if you're not willing to invest a lot of time and money, I'd suggest that you use another (customizable) map control instead of MkMapView. There are plenty of different options available, both free and paid.

Comment: Thank you. You have confirmed my conclusions. Sorry, Not reputed enough to upvote.

Comment: @Ubaid Good to hear, you can still accept the question as answered :)